# Check multiple checkboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array something like

```
var values = ['1','3','4','5'];
```

I have the list of checkboxes

```
<div id='list'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='1' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='2' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='3' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='4' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='5' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='6' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='7' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='8' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='9' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='10' />
</div>
```

now I want to select checkboxes whose values lies within array values. I have done this

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    $("#list [value=" + values[i] + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

it is working fine but can I do it without for loop.

Thank you in advance to helpers.

Comment: What's wrong with the for loop?

Comment: You should use `prop` instead of `attr` for boolean values. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
$("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z5vZ8/)

Comment: I think I'd rather us a loop for the sake of readability but +1 for giving the op what he asked for.

Comment: Isn't this identical to @Blazemongers, just with an added find?

Answer (score 9):

You could do this even more succinctly with a single combined selector:

```
$('#list [value="'+values.join('"],[value="')+'"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Which produces a selector like:

```
$('#list [value="1"],[value="3"],[value="4"],[value="5"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/jgqm4/

Comment: Issue with this is that if there are multiple elements that contain `value="2"` that ARE NOT a child of `#list`, this will pick up elements that are not a child of `#list`. Therefore, you want to produce something such as `$('#list [value="1"], #list [value="3"], #list [value="4"],#list [value="5"]')`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` like below, but it is same as `for` loop though..

```
$('#list :checkbox').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray(this.value, values) >= 0;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: it still uses an iteration

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, I did mention that.. but it is a better approach than using a `for..loop`

Comment: Why is it a better approach than a for loop or each? It is much harder to read

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your for-loop with $.each

**JQuery**

```
$.each(values, function() {
  $("#list [value=" + this + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me

   `$.each(values, function() {
       $("#list['value="' + this + '"]').attr("checked", "checked");
   });`

is the right combination