# Select multiple checkboxes in a GSP table using one checkbox

Tags: jquery, grails, checkbox, gsp

I have a GSP in a Grails application where I have a table with one columns with checkboxes. What I am trying to achieve is have a checkbox in its header which when checked, will check all the checkboxes in the column. I tried looking online and on SO, but I was surprised to find no questions related to this. If someone could give me some insight on this, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Not sure if you have a question answered with the Grails tag, but this is more a jquery generic question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614731/check-multiple-checkboxes-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can assign all the checkboxes in the column the same class, e.g. `columnCheckbox` then this should do it

```
$('#headerCheckbox').click(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $('.columnCheckbox').prop('checked', checked);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/6274/)